# How to get oracle killed exceptions

Tags: oracle

I have the following structure in my stored procedure:

```
loop
try
  update some record to state "1"
  make some process
  update that record to state "2"
  commit 
exception
  update that record to state "3" //error !
end
end loop
```

Now lets supose that there is an error like session kill, or client disconnect, while this loop is running.
How can I threat this error? The try..exception is not working. I need to write "3" to the state field of my record.

Comment: you can't because those "exceptions" are basically destroying the foundation your code is running on...

Comment: Those are not code errors that you can handle.

Comment: i once did it with an odbc client on top of oracle. you can catch `ORA-00028: your session has been killed` exceptions and know that your session had been killed. i'm not sure you can catch and handle this exception in pl/sql code because, well, your session had been killed and disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider:

```
loop
try
  update some record to state "3"
  commit
  update some record to state "1"
  make some process
  update that record to state "2"
  commit 
end
end loop
```

So, you start by setting the status to "3" and commit. Then you start your actual processing. If your session is killed before the process ends, changes since the first commit will be rolled back, so the status will be rolled back to "3". If your processing ends successfully, changes will be commited and your status will be set to "2".

I don't really understand why you set status to "1", it will never be visible outside the transaction, as it is always overwritten by "2" before transaction commit.

Comment: You are right, there is a commit after update to "1". Your aproach is good, but, the user will see this record in a status of "3" until the end of the process. Maybe he take some action because of this, and this is not acceptable.